# How to derive this partial sum about a harmonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've recently run across an equation in a proof that I'd love to get help with. It argues that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} i \frac{1}{iH_{N}} = \frac{N}{H_{N}}$$

Where $H_{N}$ is the Nth Harmonic Number (sum of the harmonic series calculated at N, I believe.) I'm not sure if the harmonic series even matters here though (it's useful for a later step in the proof which I do get), so that may be a red herring.

Would anyone be willing to walk me through this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The $i$'s cancel and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{H_N} \sum_{i=1}^N 1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Oh man, I was afraid it was that simple :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by *Donald Splutterwit* it is quite simple as the index cancels. Thus, we have that
$$\sum_{i=1}^Ni\frac1{iH_N}=\frac1{H_N}\sum_{i=1}^N1=\frac1{H_N}N$$

> $$\therefore~\sum_{k=1}^Ni\frac1{iH_N}~=~\frac N{H_N}$$

It is always worth to look for cancelation and what is constant regarding the summation and what is not as this example brilliantly illustrates. So, the problems appears hard, as we are facing a repciprocal harmonic number, but as we can see this is not important at all.